# Open Chrome/Firefox/Opera inside our App

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I am developing an Android app in which I want to allow user to search anything on internet.

**IDEA:**
I have added a WebView, EditText and a Button. Anything user writes in EditText and clicks on Button. It's search result will be displayed on WebView. It is not an issue. It is done. What I want to say is, Is it possible that we can integrate Chrome/Firefox/Opera inside our app. I mean we don't need to add WebView/EditText/Button. Open these browsers separately, can we open them inside our app in any tab.... I just want to ask that is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The short answer is no. You can't you can still launch that browser using an intent.

Comment: You can use chrome technology in your app like integrate chrome custom tabs instead of normal `WebView` see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOxIdbNwpx0&feature=youtu.be), but about your question see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21451379/4043944).